# python os.fork child process ID is not continuous

Tags: python

I am trying on `os.fork` function using CPython 3.7.2
Here is the example

```
def main():
    data = 222

    childPid = os.fork()
    if childPid == -1:
        print('error on fork child')
    elif childPid == 0:
        data *= 3
    else:
        time.sleep(3)

    print("PID=%d data=%d" % (os.getpid(), data))
```

When I use C language, I always get 2 continuous PID for parent and child.
However in python, I always get PID which are not continuous( for example here I got `21475` and `21442`).

```
PID=21475 data=666
PID=21442 data=222
```

Don't understand how it behave not same.

Comment: Why would it matter?

Comment: just curious, cause since it is CPython, if we use the same system call in low level, the OS usually allocate next free PID for child which I read from book, so I am wondering why they behave not same

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be consecutive in *any* language -- not in C either. Writing code that depends on behavior that isn't a documented guarantee is a path to pain and suffering; building your mental models on such observations, likewise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow requires that questions be ["based on actual problems that you face"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and this is a matter of curiosity: The behavior at hand is explicitly and intentionally implementation-defined and subject to change at any time for any reason or no reason at all.

Comment: It's the same system call, yes, but in C there's less likelihood of the thread being preempted and another process being created in the meantime.

Comment: @CSJ I ran your code 20 times, and always saw the child PID equal to the parent PID plus 1.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, seems in some environment the result not same, so it is the low level implement python issue, let me close this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIDs are not guaranteed to be consecutive, although they typically are (on Linux). If a PID is already in use, it will be skipped.

If you saw consecutive PIDs when testing C code, it's because you happened to not come across an in-use PID. There should be no difference in behavior between `fork()` in C and `os.fork()` in Python.

Comment: To add to this -- PIDS are generated sequentially. However, there are numerous situations where a PID won't be sequential (such as an existing PID already in existence with the next PID value in the sequence). In that situation, the kernel will create a PID with the next available value in the sequence.

One should not expect PIDS to be sequential when forking processes. The only guarantee is that all PIDs are unique (there are never two PIDs given the same number).

Comment: What you describe is accurate for Linux, but not for some BSDs where [PIDs are randomly assigned](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/88692/35748).

Comment: I am curious why the `next available` always not consecutive when I use python, looks like 100% chance. and my working system is not that busy

Comment: Use `strace` or `sysdig` or somesuch to look at the actual syscalls. If there *is* any actual difference in what the runtimes are doing, it will necessarily be exposed at the syscall layer. And as `sysdig` gives you a full-system view of *all* your processes at any point in time, its logs include tracking which PIDs are at use at the time of each `fork()`.

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart -- good point. That's an important detail to know.